# Hardware watchpoints - how do they work?

Tags: debugging, gdb, hardware, watchpoint

How do GDB watchpoints work? Can similar functionality be implemented to harness byte level access at defined locations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe gdb uses the MMU so that the memory pages containing watched address ranges are marked as protected - then when an exception occurs for a write to a protected pages gdb handles the exception, checks to see whether the address of the write corresponds to a particular watchpoint, and then either resumes or drops to the gdb command prompt accordingly.

You can implement something similar for your own debugging code or test harness using [mprotect](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mprotect), although you'll need to implement an exception handler if you want to do anything more sophisticated than just fail on a bad write.

Comment: thanks for the information. Is there any kind of support from the hardware available. I know thats just a shot in the dark.

Comment: The MMU (Memory Management Unit) *is* hardware - by marking a page as protected you can get an exception on a write to that page - this is how hardware-assisted watchpoints work. Without the MMU you'd have to pause after every instruction and examine all watchpoint address ranges - this is how software watchpoints typically work on systems without MMUs (e.g. small embedded systems) and it's *very* slow.

Answer (score 13):

On x86 there are CPU debug registers D0-D3 that track memory address.

[This](https://www.kernel.org/doc/ols/2009/ols2009-pages-149-158.pdf) explains how hardware breakpoints are implemented in Linux and also gives details of what processor specific features are used.

Another [article](http://lwn.net/Articles/353050/) on hardware breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Using the MMU or an MPU (on other processors such as embedded), can be used to implement "hardware watchpoints"; however, some processors (e.g., many Arm implementations) have dedicated watchpoint hardware accessed via a debug port. This has some advantages over using an MMU or MPU.

If you use the MMU or MPU approach:

1. PRO - There is no special hardware needed for application-class processors because an MMU is built-in to support the needs of Linux or Windows. In the case of specialized realtime-class processors, there is often an MPU.
2. CON - There will be software overhead handling the exception. This is probably not a problem for an Application class processor (e.g., x86); however, for embedded realtime-application, this could spell disaster.
3. CON- MMU or MPU faults may happen for other reasons, which means the handler will need to figure our exactly why it faulted by reading various status registers.
4. PRO - using MMU memory protection faults can often cover many separate variables to watchpoint many variables easily. However, this not normally required of most debugging situations.

If you use dedicated debug watchpoint hardware such as supported by Arm:

1. PRO - There is no impact on software performance (helps if debugging subtle timing issues). The debug infrastructure is designed to be non-intrusive.
2. CON - There are a limited number of these hardware units on any particular silicon. For Arm, there may be 0, 2 or 4 of these. So you need to be careful to choose. The units can cover a range of addresses, but there are limits. For some processors, they may even be limited to the region of memory.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32821342)