# The right way to use function _mm_clflush to flush a large struct

Tags: c, x86, cpu-cache, sse2, clflush

I am starting to use functions like `_mm_clflush`, `_mm_clflushopt`, and `_mm_clwb`.

Say now as I have defined a struct name mystruct and its size is 256 Bytes. My cacheline size is 64 Bytes. Now I want to flush the cacheline that contains the mystruct variable. Which of the following way is the right way to do so?

```
_mm_clflush(&mystruct)
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(mystruct)/64; i++) {

     _mm_clflush( ((char *)&mystruct) + i*64)

}
```

Comment: Neither.  You need 4 flushes 64 bytes apart (assuming your struct is aligned by 64), not 4 flushes at the first 4 bytes.  So `i<sizeof(mystruct) ; i+=64`

Comment: Sorry that I write it wrong. Let me amend my errors.

Comment: how about now ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `clflush` CPU instruction doesn't know the size of your struct; it only flushes exactly one cache line, the one containing the byte pointed to by the pointer operand.  (The C intrinsic exposes this as a `const void*`, but `char*` would also make sense, especially given the [asm documentation](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/clflush) which describes it as an 8-bit memory operand.)

**You need 4 flushes 64 bytes apart, or maybe 5** if your struct isn't `alignas(64)` so it could have parts in 5 different lines.  (You could unconditionally flush the last byte of the struct, instead of using more complex logic to check if it's in a cache line you haven't flushed yet, depending on relative cost of `clflush` vs. more logic and a possible branch mispredict.)

Your original loop did 4 flushes of 4 adjacent bytes at the start of your struct.
It's probably easiest to use pointer increments so the casting is not mixed up with the critical logic.

```
// first attempt, a bit clunky:
    const int LINESIZE = 64;
    const char *lastbyte = (const char *)(&mystruct+1) - 1;
    for (const char *p = (const char *)&mystruct; p <= lastbyte ; p+=LINESIZE) {
         _mm_clflush( p );
    }
    // if mystruct is guaranteed aligned by 64, you're done.  Otherwise not:

    // check if next line to maybe flush contains the last byte of the struct; if not then it was already flushed.
    if( ((uintptr_t)p ^ (uintptr_t)lastbyte) & -LINESIZE == 0 )
        _mm_clflush( lastbyte );
```

`x^y` is 1 in bit-positions where they differ.  `x & -LINESIZE` discards the offset-within-line bits of the address, keeping only the line-number bits.  So we can see if 2 addresses are in the same cache line or not with just XOR and TEST instructions.  (Or clang optimizes that to a shorter `cmp` instruction).

**Or rewrite that into a single loop, using that if logic as the termination condition:**

I used a C++ `struct foo &var` reference so I could follow your `&var` syntax but still see how it compiles for a function taking a pointer arg.  Adapting to C is straightforward.

#### Looping over every cache line of an arbitrary size unaligned struct

```
/* I think this version is best: 
  * compact setup / small code-size
  * with no extra latency for the initial pointer
  * doesn't need to peel a final iteration
*/
inline
void flush_structfoo(struct foo &mystruct) {
    const int LINESIZE = 64;
    const char *p = (const char *)&mystruct;
    uintptr_t endline = ((uintptr_t)&mystruct + sizeof(mystruct) - 1) | (LINESIZE-1);
    // set the offset-within-line address bits to get the last byte 
    // of the cacheline containing the end of the struct.

    do {   // flush while p is in a cache line that contains any of the struct
         _mm_clflush( p );
          p += LINESIZE;
    } while(p <= (const char*)endline);
}
```

With GCC10.2 -O3 for x86-64, this [compiles nicely (Godbolt)](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAZlICsupVs1qgA%2BhOSkAzpnbICeOpUy10AYVSsArgFtag1egAyeWpgByegEaZiIbrwAOqaYSW1NO/YJdvFdKbmVrq29o4ycpgKHgwEzMQEXnoGnJHyAbRxCQRBljZ2IABMAGwy8YnJPmnSFblm%2BaGFpQCUMqjaxMgcAOQApEXcZsg6WADUfdzqeLq6ZgTEZgB0CJPYfQAMAIIDQ7Qj2uOT6rX49CtrmzvbtcTaCmM0qH0A7ABCV2NfYwD0P2PIBAJMbMPoAVjeRTBJQmRTeY044IAIpN4WMAOLqdRjVBORRzABemGkIIA7swAJ5jAgITAAuj4TIksyPHTSBBiABunDGthY2lkY0IYB6JLY5IpJMwAA9mApWFSwWNWA1pJ9vvMQeDIdCfgAWZGoq6vFHcD7bY3bTmoPDoVkCjnciC3e4ER6oVCwkq6SULV0tCbvdVfNC0WpC%2BhjYwASQs2AY0YAWtgJtwkWMSgazcH6WG3YDgQAqJyp9MQUPhgvEMaFloDb2%2Bu4KI3bb65ytA6uF4S1awUgh0yZliv5zs1loQes%2Bl3NuGcAMAWgRLa2bZo1cnZrGJeOyuYvf7g63TgGHzTMbjCeTAde5tXbbbYlmYhGVDZCAg27Gdezre%2BJpzP4hSoMZpz9B48BJYBtASEQB0wO02DwYBzDtPsMz1UgxgpDoRWIOl0DoTAli%2BAB5Gk7FJSC6VoVACBAY1BjwEDET/L4gMBaIAGtgLGcxpTdFVzGpT1dEpWx7XZXN4jMEkKL3cM%2BwHHEQPkmcCFRXjaLdCjaCFN1yTFVh8OYdAqTfB0EKWHNmM/KAIG0eY8WIMQCBaHcwRTBynIWVyWh7AglMwG9SjGBcL3jJNsADMAwCHMYNm/HNH2fV930/AKgqS38dkGIxmONF4UQtK0bTtCz2S5IpnXAt0ni9MCmzcwM7zbEcIzdCKrxTeLMxXNtHPoZzXOVBpSzGbyht8typ0bV0vTCrqov675BoIYbBP3AghKPMtJvW6a61KRr5tPMY3CJVAqAgE6FEXBEQphcLY0i5MVq%2BQiWofb62yA8VKTFQTMC2nFhIq1Yt1JEguJJOhzrE1hWHO2q1TY76n10F9WHBuzrVtWsduy1qfq%2BQnT3ipa3pytsTTGUkEDwdgIDJqYFO2hofzvQriuuLYgIAFQZ2HhNYD0Yd5YkNNK21JMdbgaqa91PVm9SbyDNH2s1SmerTDD3vbUcix3XXyzoDsiyOht1P1taNrGIwWb223DpV2rYXhC7MCum65rusKHsDbEIG1hd5xXHNPtvb4gPBumGfYL9IIjEEATlWlRuEmlmHzOgZLDEFaCpK7qXT620YfDGsZxr9OeSh8dzhCmXu6/XafpxnMAgY31Hi028wBTtawdjnw%2B2H5CxzddNzebve/aqsCa2ln4Qbs9021ut3m%2BoDcXxPAiWrQjiVoEU3RMlUiRLpOk/%2ByVqTuOl5KoPBiHDQg7Gzjw6%2B%2BSu0odT8Sy1zRgBbYhYfjcyuD0NorAQA9DBD0UgBgegbAQagWB2JpAdC6IOQYnAEH0WQVAtoXEQBgiKEsRwAAOF4eoACc3AXiUNoWCbgtDaFCFgXqBBuguAbA2Ig2BKDSBoJ6Ag6QIB%2BEEJQW0OAsAkBoF0E4DuZAKCm0UcolAwBOAbCKKQZ%2BrAByv0oNYQRCDrBmASBSWBeDSAKN0KoAgpFaAKlMaQLAYlRDsFcfgfCMROTElcTKaI2gBzWIQfMOQriVTWGIJYzQWAwmkAWDMMJbQaD0CYGwDgnBdECDSMIUQIAJAviEHgaw4jIBtF3h4cRPQFwAHU2BIwaTKBYzAwqkW4GFaUyByZwjEVEGIygIBGCqKkUgRg8ghDCL4Vw7g6BjNmf4DwUyCj2BqIMzI2RKhaBSIIWQGRYh1FWU0dZ5QciLJqMcho0zCjznaJ0boXBoGwPgQIwhwjYHSkoSUBcmYxjAGQMgBEGwlhFAmrgQgJBYTcDSGMTQ6j2DVl2POeF%2BDTEtGISAPULwlglBKDksEGwShFG0XqMEbDMIwJ6Fw0gPDtH8KQUIkRYiJFJIxS8noRRuG8MZa4ll7LCGYtIP41%2BHhsVAA%3D)

```
flush_v3(foo&):
        lea     rax, [rdi+255]
        or      rax, 63
.L11:
        clflush [rdi]
        add     rdi, 64
        cmp     rdi, rax
        jbe     .L11
        ret
```

GCC doesn't unroll, and doesn't optimize any better if you use `alignas(64) struct foo{...};` unfortunately.  You might use `if (alignof(mystruct) >= 64) { ... }` to check if special handling is needed to let GCC optimize better, otherwise just use `end = p + sizeof(mystruct);` or `end = (const char*)(&mystruct+1) - 1;` or similar.

(In C, `#include <stdalign.h>` for #define for `alignas()` and `alignof()` like C++, instead of ISO C11 `_Alignas` and `_Alignof` keywords.)

---

Another alternative is this, but it's clunkier and takes more setup work.

```
    const int LINESIZE = 64;
    uintptr_t line = (uintptr_t)&mystruct & -LINESIZE;
    uintptr_t lastline = ((uintptr_t)&mystruct + sizeof(mystruct) - 1) & -LINESIZE;
    do {               // always at least one flush; works on small structs
         _mm_clflush( (void*)line );
          line += LINESIZE;
    } while(line < lastline);
```

A struct that was 257 bytes would always touch exactly 5 cache lines, no checking needed.  Or a 260-byte struct that's known to be aligned by 4.  IDK if we can get GCC to optimize away the checks based on that.

Comment: For the edge case, why not just execute another flush on the final byte of the struct if it is not 64-Byte-aligned? Something like: "if ( &struct%64 != 0) _mm_clflush( (char *)&struct + sizeof(struct) -1 );"

Comment: @JohnDMcCalpin: I was trying to come up with something that didn't depend on `sizeof(struct) % 64 == 0`, for the general case. You're right that for a 256-byte struct like in this question, that works and is a lot simpler.