# x86_64 check if power of 2 load / store will page cross for 2 pointers

Tags: assembly, x86-64, micro-optimization

Basically I am looking to implement the following in x86_64 assembly as fast as possible.  (Where `foo` and `bar` may be something like glibc's hand-written asm strcpy or strcmp, and we want to start out with wide vectors but without the safety and/or performance downsides of a page-split load when one isn't needed.  Or of an AVX-512 masked store: fault suppression works for correctness but is slow if it has to actually suppress a fault in the destination.)

```
#define TYPE __m256i
int has_page_cross(void * ptr1, void * ptr2) {
   uint64_t ptr1_u64 = (uint64_t)ptr1;
   uint64_t ptr2_u64 = (uint64_t)ptr2;
   ptr1_u64 &= 4095;
   ptr2_u64 &= 4095;
   if((ptr1_u64 + sizeof(TYPE)) > 4096
      || (ptr2_u64 + sizeof(TYPE)) > 4096) {
      // There will be a page cross
      return foo_handling_page_cross(ptr1, ptr2);
   }
   return bar_with_no_page_cross(ptr1, ptr2);
}
```

There are a lot of really efficient ways to do this for one pointer many of which are discussed in [Is it safe to read past the end of a buffer within the same page on x86 and x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37801845/11322131) but there does not seem to be a particularly efficient approach for two pointers that does not sacrifice accuracy.

Approaches

From here on out assuming `ptr1` is starting in `rdi` and `ptr2` is starting in `rsi`. Load size will be represented by constant `LSIZE`.

#### Fast with False Positives

```
                                        // cycles, bytes
    movl    %edi, %eax                  // 0     , 2   # assuming mov-elimination
    orl     %esi, %eax                  // 0     , 5   #  which Ice Lake disabled
    andl    $4095, %eax                 // 1     , 10
    cmpl    $(4096 - LSIZE), %eax       // 2     , 15
    ja      L(page_cross)              

    /* less bytes       
    movl    %edi, %eax                  // 0     , 2
    orl     %esi, %eax                  // 1     , 5
    sall    $20, %eax                   // 2     , 8
    cmpl    $(4096 - LSIZE) << 20, %eax // 3     , 13
    ja      L(page_cross)
     */
```

- Latency   : 3c
- Throughput: ~1.08c Measured (both versions).
- Bytes     : 13b

This approach is nice because it is fast with 3c latency (assuming eliminated `movl %edi, %eax`), has high throughput, and is pretty compact for the Front End.

The obvious drawback is that it will have false positive i.e `rdi = 4000`, `rsi = 95`. I think though that its performance should serve as the goal for a full correct solution.

#### Slower but Correct

This is the best I've been able to come up with

```
                                        // cycles, bytes
    leal    (LSIZE - 1)(%rdi), %eax     // 0     , 4
    leal    (LSIZE - 1)(%rsi), %edx     // 0     , 8
    xorl    %edi, %eax                  // 1     , 11
    xorl    %esi, %edx                  // 1     , 14
    orl     %edx, %eax                  // 2     , 17
    testl   $4096, %eax                 // 3     , 22
    jnz     L(page_cross)
```

- Latency   : 4c
- Throughput: ~1.75c Measured (Note on Icelake so higher tput `lea` than older CPUs)
- Bytes     : 21b

It has a 4c latency which isn't so bad, but its throughput is worse, and it has a much larger code footprint.

#### Question

1. Can either of these approaches be improved at all in terms of latency, throughput, or bytes? Generally I am most interested in latency > throughput > bytes?

My general goal is to get the correct case as fast as the false positive.

Edit:
Fixed bug in Correct version.

CPUs:
Personally I am tuning for CPUs with AVX512 so Skylake Server, Icelake, and Tigerlake but this question is targetted at entire Sandybridge family.

Comment: If you're tuning for Ice Lake, note that a microcode update disabled mov-elimination for integer registers to work around the ICL065 erratum.  https://www.realworldtech.com/forum/?threadid=200635&curpostid=200659.  So a dependent OR can't run in the same cycle as MOV

Comment: Note that false positives aren't a correctness problem, so it's a tradeoff that depends on how much extra cost  `foo_handling_page_cross` has, as well as the false-positive rate.  I guess for fault-suppression of an AVX-512 masked store for strcpy, it's pretty significant for small copies, and critically *doesn't* fault in the page so it can happen repeatedly for copies into the same buffer.  (Even if it was copy-on-write or otherwise read-only in the page tables, but still logically allocated by malloc.)

Comment: I think correct solution needs to use `LSIZE - 1` for addition (lea)?

Comment: @PeterCordes Icelake was just the benchmark CPU, not tuning for it specifically. Added edit.

Answer (score 4):

With a single false positive at `a % 4096 == 4096 - size`, you could use this:

```
~a & (4096 - size) == 0
```

translates to assembly:

```
  not edi
  not esi
  test edi, (4096 - size)
  jz crosses-page-boundary
  test esi, (4096 - size)
  jz crosses-page-boundary
  (2 cycle latency)
```

Explanation: For size=32, we want the last 12-bits of the address to be larger than 4096 - 32 = 4064 = `0b1111'1110'0000`. We know a number can be equal or larger than this number only if it has all the same leading 1-bits and anything in the low 5 bits. We can't test if all the specified bits are one easily, so we invert the bits and test if they're all zero with `test edi, (4096 - size)`.

---

Note you could shift the false positive to `a % 4096 == 0` (which I reckon is worse since it's more likely to happen?) by using `neg` instead of `not` (`-a = ~a + 1`, so if all low 5-bit values were zero, then after inversion they become 1 and adding one carries it into the tested region which makes it a false positive for `a % 4096 == 0`, but hides the false positive for `a % 4096 == 4096 - size`).

Comment: How efficiently could this be done with only one branch?  I feel like it must be possible more efficiently than what ICC is doing when using `|` on two booleans (https://godbolt.org/z/z15a85qh3) (gcc and clang just branch twice), maybe with an `or` instruction somewhere, or somehow an `andn`?  I guess just ORing the two pointers and checking if the resulting offset is near the end of a page would work, but that introduces a huge possibility of false positives.

Comment: @PeterCordes Maybe they can be combined with a shift? I.e something along the lines of (but more efficient than) [this](https://godbolt.org/z/Es9zzPvMn). The fact than shift will zero lower bits seems ripe for an `andn` but can't seem to make it work.

Comment: @Stephan nice! that is realy fast and faster / less code than the stuff in [Is it safe to read past the end of a buffer within the same page on x86 and x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800739/is-it-safe-to-read-past-the-end-of-a-buffer-within-the-same-page-on-x86-and-x64/37801845#37801845) for one page cross. A bit concerns about 2 branches though.

Comment: Thinking about this a bit more I guess this solution trades the 1 false positive for either 1b of code or 2 more ports for first instructions as compared with `not` -> `andl` / `sall`. Guess is pretty data dependent whether thats a win.

Comment: @Noah test on both of them (after a shift) makes it "a crosses page boundary" *and* "b crosses page boundary". That seems to be the culprit for one branch :p