# `test reg, const` when `reg` contains a memory address

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

While trying to reverse engineer a "crackme" binary, I stumbled upon a function that starts like this:

```
mov ecx, [esp+4]
test ecx, 3
jz short loc_106A9F0
```

The first argument for the function (which is `MOV`'d to `ECX` in the first line of the function) is a pointer to a string. If I understand correctly, the next line performs the `TEST` operation with one operand being a memory address and the other being a constant. I was wondering why a program might do that, considering the fact that the memory address itself should be irrelevant.
In short, I'm wondering why would a program `TEST` a pointer with a non-zero const.

Answer (score 6):

It's checking for 4-byte alignment of the pointer, i.e. for both of the low 2 bits being zero, so
`p % 4 == 0`

That's something you might do at the start of an optimized strlen or similar function that reads memory more than one byte at a time; see [Is it safe to read past the end of a buffer within the same page on x86 and x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37800739)

Or it could be for a tagged-pointer thing where you use the low 2 bits of an `int *` for something else, because a real `int *` will always have 2 zero bits at the bottom (on a byte-addressable machine like x86, in a C implementation with `alignof(int) == 4`).  You clear them before dereferencing the pointer, or extract them to get at the extra data.  It might be plausible to be branching on them being both clear.