# How to load 48-bit of data using SSE

Tags: c, performance, simd, sse

I'm using SIMD for the first time so please excuse me if this is a basic question.

Essentially I am processing RGB24 images. For my algorithm I need to load 2 pixels at once, 48-bit in total. `_mm_loadl_epi64` at first glance it looks perfect if you say you don't care about the additional 16-bit, which I don't. But the image I have is given from an external library. I cannot know the alignment. This means if I access the last two pixels I am 16-bit out of bounds of allocated memory.

Is it correct to say that this is UB? Or is it fine to just ignore this? What would be an (hopefully) efficient alternative to using `_mm_loadl_epi64` to load just 48-bit data? I tried to use `_mm_set_epi8` and literally just pass in the `uint8_t` values but it was wildly slower.

Comment: Related: [Is it safe to read past the end of a buffer within the same page on x86 and x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37800739) - you could check `(ptr & -4096) <= 4096-8` or something to avoid crossing a page boundary.  (Hopefully try to avoid checking inside an inner loop, like calculate something.)  Of course, it's much better if you can pad your buffer some so there are 2 bytes allocated past the end of the last actual pixel.

Comment: One simple thing you could do is `_mm_loadu_si32` (`movd` 1 uop) + `_mm_insert_epi16` (`pinsrw` 2 uops).  But that's quite a lot worse than one `movq`, especially if you're going to `_mm_shuffle_epi8` or something else that gets rid of the 2 garbage bytes for free.

Comment: This is probably only relevant for the very last 1--2 pixels, which you could just handle manually outside your loop. Another alternative: load at `(ptr-2)` and shift the value (or if you shuffle anyways, use different shuffle indexes).

Comment: Oh yes, definitely if looping over pixels, yeah just special-case the last 2.  That makes much more sense.  Otherwise you can normally do at least 4 pixels per vector (12 bytes), or 5 pixels (15 bytes), or unroll to 3 loads of 16 bytes (48 bytes = 16 pixels, if that doesn't suck too much for shuffling if you need to unpack to 16-bit integers.)

Comment: Unfortunately it's the other way around, I'm looping over coordinates, apply a transform which give me the x/y in the image. So I can't say just skip the last iteration or something like that. Any particular iteration may land me on that final pixel.

Comment: @chtz Well with `(ptr-2)` I have the same problem but on the very first pixel :p

Comment: @JohnSmith You can *clamp* the loading position to `(end - 8 bytes)`. This will work when your image has size of at least 2x1 or 1x2 pixels, and for smaller images SIMD is probably not worth it. Depending on what you do with the loaded data, you may need to also adjust the shuffle mask to account for the possibly clamped loading position.